# Why doesn't my Windows Store (Metro) app appear in the Share Pane?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have made my app a Share Target (and Source), and I can successfully Share my app's content with other apps, but when I am in another app, like Mail or IE for example, I cannot share their content with my app because it doesn't appear in the Share Pane as an available Share Target app.

I have read and followed the MSDN documentation, checked out the samples, and have also setup the Share Target Declaration in the Package.AppXManifest file.

Why, and how can I fix this?

---

C# Code-behind:

```
    ShareOperation shareOperation;
    private string sharedDataTitle;
    private string sharedDataDescription;
    private string shareQuickLinkId;
    private string sharedText;
    private Uri sharedUri;
    private IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> sharedStorageItems;
    private string sharedCustomData;
    private string sharedHtmlFormat;
    private IReadOnlyDictionary<string, RandomAccessStreamReference> sharedResourceMap;
    private IRandomAccessStreamReference sharedBitmapStreamRef;
    private IRandomAccessStreamReference sharedThumbnailStreamRef;

    private void ReportStarted()
    {
        this.shareOperation.ReportStarted();
    }

    private void ReportCompleted()
    {
        this.shareOperation.ReportCompleted();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterForShare();

        try
        {
            this.shareOperation = (ShareOperation)e.Parameter;
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    ReportStarted();
                    // Retrieve data package properties.
                    this.sharedDataTitle = this.shareOperation.Data.Properties.Title;
                    this.sharedDataDescription = this.shareOperation.Data.Properties.Description;
                    this.shareQuickLinkId = this.shareOperation.QuickLinkId;

                    // Retrieve data package content.
                    if (this.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            this.sharedText = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetTextAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            // NotifyUser of error.
                        }
                    }
                    else if(this.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Html))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            this.sharedHtmlFormat = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetHtmlFormatAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if (this.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Uri))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            this.sharedUri = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetUriAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    // Get back to the UI thread.
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                        {
                            if (this.sharedText != null)
                            {
                                // Create a Note out of shared data.
                                CreateNote(this.sharedDataTitle, this.sharedText, null);
                                this.shareOperation.ReportDataRetrieved();
                            }

                            if (this.sharedUri != null)
                            {
                                CreateNote(this.sharedDataTitle, this.sharedUri.OriginalString, null);
                                this.shareOperation.ReportDataRetrieved();
                            }

                            if (this.sharedHtmlFormat != null)
                            {
                                CreateNote(this.sharedDataTitle, this.sharedHtmlFormat.ToString(), null);
                                this.shareOperation.ReportDataRetrieved();
                            }
                        });
                });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);

        }

        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            navigatedBack = true;


        }

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.ShareOperation);
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package manifest, make sure you add the declaration for "share target"

Comment: As stated in my question, I have already done that. It still doesn't work. I have even supplied all relevant DataFormats and Supported File Types.

Comment: The problem is in the declaration, that's how windows knows it can share to the app.  Perhaps you added it, but didn't set it up correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Javalsu. There was a period before one of the DataFormats.